# Is there limit sending and receiving data via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have dynamic webpage that import `html` data via ajax and set that `responseText` append to div. Is it professional that applying `php` processed `html` in to a div. is there limit when receiving and sending data via `ajax`?

this is my sample code

server side `php` code like this

```
echo '<div>large html data<div>';
```

Its very long html

This is my Javascript code

```
$.post('getHTML.php',
    {msg:$("#main-panel").val()},
    function(responseText){
    $("#main-panel").empty();
    $("#main-panel").append(responseText);
})
```

or Do i need to add elements one by one?

Comment: The limit (or lack thereof) is the same as any other request.

Comment: ajax is http. that's it. it's got the same limits as any other http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajax` is anathor form of `http`. it is same as other `http` requests. `ajax` use `http` requests when getting or sending data. you need a proper introduction to `ajax`. [ajax http requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started/%22HTTP%20request%22)